# Spinner when loads data from Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I try to create a spinner when loading data from Firebase. I am new to this, so sorry for the basics question. I've come up with this code so far. Declare state , and try to add a conditional statement, but no success:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      items: [],
      loading: true
    };
    this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('items');
    this._handleResults = this._handleResults.bind(this);
  }

 listenForItems(itemsRef) {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
    itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {

      // get children as an array
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        items.push({
          french: child.val().french,
          english: child.val().english,
          english_erudite: child.val().english_erudite,
          _key: child.key
        });
      });

      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items),
        items: items,
        loading: false
      });

    });
  }

 _renderItem(item) {
     const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
     const {loading}= this.state;

    if (this.state.loading){
      return <Spinner/>
      }else{
       return(<ListItem item={item} onPress={() =>
       navigate('Details', {...item} )} />);
     }
  }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no success"? What is the behavior you are getting and what do you expect?

Comment: Actually I have a syntax error on line 142, could not detect why...

Comment: Your sampled code does not have 142 lines. Could you point it out?